# PreviousPage.Property is Nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Default.aspx page which has some Public ReadOnly Properties that get their values from HiddenFields on the page. The page is eventually redirected to Users/Main.aspx. On Main.aspx I have a @ PreviousPageType reference with a VirtualPath parameter set to "~/Default.aspx". In the codebehind to Main.aspx I have

```
lb_Username.Text = PreviousPage.Username
```

When I run in debug the system complains that PreviousPage = Nothing

What have I done wrong? More code can be supplied if necessary.

Comment: How are you moving from one page to the other? You need to use Server.Transfer not Response.Redirect in order to use PreviousPage I believe.

Comment: Tom, yes I was using Response.Redirect but changing to Server.Transfer has given the same result... PreviousPage = Nothing. The transfer is in the LoadComplete event of Default.aspx, so the page is 'loaded' before it is redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom you were correct... I had another branch in the code which also used Response.Redirect. Once I had change them all to use Server.Transfer PreviousPage.*Object* gave me values.
Many Thanks